# How to have my own language to WordPress Site for Post, Title, Menu bar, links and other things?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, custom-wordpress-pages

Hey I am building a website and it needs Nepali language in the front-end and the menu, post, title, quick links, categories all should be in Nepali language.
Is there a way to make Nepali language default keeping the Back-end language in English as default.

Comment: You mean, the post title should be Nepali in the frontend, and english in the backend?

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant. But I found the solution anyway. So, thank your for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want front-end to be nepali language this is pretty simple thing. When creating pages give them nepali title and same for posts. When creating menu add nepali pages and name automatic be nepali. Everything inside wordpress you create use nepali titles.

if you want to modify other things use header.php, single.php and page.php and footer.php to modify words into Nepali.

In case if you want backend as well in Nepali go to Settings -> General and change the language to nepali.